# Meteor prevent re-loading data on each edit?

Tags: meteor

I'm working on my first Meteor project – took over someone else's code with 80% of the app completed.

We have an object model which is fairly large and complex, sort of like:

```
something: { ... }
attachments: [ {...}, {...}, ...]
another-thing: { ... },
....
```

It's loaded using (so we are using `LocalCollection.Cursor` and not fetching):

```
Inspections.findOne({_id: inspection_id})
```

This object populates a template which is split up into several individual component templates.

Within one of these component templates the user can update various properties. For example selecting or de-selecting attachments:

```
Object.attachments[0].selected = true;
```

We then update like so (where `updatedAttachments` is the updated attachments array):

```
InspectionOrders.update({ _id: inspection._id }, {
  $set: {
    attachments:updatedAttachments
  }
});
```

The problem is attachments (and some other properties) load a bunch of other data from a which can take a while. Changing `select` state takes takes 3-4 seconds to re-render because all these little attachments are being downloaded again.

**My questions:**

- Is there a way to handle updating this object which doesn't require downloading this data on every change?
- In general, is it a good idea to split up this object into multiple little objects? Wouldn't that still require a re-load of all objects if the parent's properties are changed?

*I tried warping parts of the template in `{{#isolate}}` but it made no difference.*

**EDIT:**

The data structure is kind of like this:

```
InspectionOrder
|
|- Attachments [file names]
|
|- Findings [keys]
```

When the page is loaded or when `InspectionOrder` is updated. All the attachments are downloaded again (image files) and all the Findings are populated again (using the reference keys).

The problem isn't the speed of update. It's the re-loading of all this data which didn't change.

Comment: You might want to store attachments in their own collection, and refer to them on the inspection objects by their ids only. Meteor stores all subscribed data on the client in the minimongo database - only the documents which have actually changed will get sent to or retrieved from the server.

Comment: Apart from splitting data into multiple collections. Is there no way to limit model update to a certain scope within meteor?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what your problem is - is it just a really, really huge document? As I understand it, the current implementation of DDP can only send whole documents. If your document is gigantic, like hundreds of KB to MBs, that would explain the lag when updating. I thought I remember reading that a later revision to DDP might allow for more granular document updates. If your documents are *that huge* though, I would think about normalizing a bit regardless.

Comment: Nevermind, according to the current spec: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/DDP.md , document updates should only contain the fields that have actually changed. The issue is that if a field is an array or nested object, that entire array or nested object is sent over the wire (rather than just the changed elements/properties). So your entire attachments array gets transmitted on every update. If the individual attachment items are really big, then you should probably normalize them into their own collection.

Comment: Ah, your update clarified the issue. If I'm not mistaken, the browser should cache the image files, so they shouldn't have to be re-downloaded. Is there any change if you run the meteor app using this command:

`meteor --release template-engine-preview-5.5`

Comment: I errors in a few templates such as: `packages/spacebars/spacebars.js:297: Can't use this stache tag at this position in an HTML tag, at line 1, offset 40 in Template "autoInspectHeader"`. I understand that images can be cached but what about the `find(_id)` that is executed for all the Findings? That seems to be the biggest issue for us.

Comment: Right sorry the new template engine doesn't allow any isolates or constants. Is there any way you could make a minimal reproduction of the issue as a gist or git repo? It would be easier to solve if I could work with the code directly.

Comment: I'll try to do that tonight. Not sure if it's possible but will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the data I'm a little unclear on where the problem is, but here are a couple of things you could try:

### update less data

Instead of setting the entire attachments array, you could just update the property that changed. For example:

```
InspectionOrders.update({_id: inspection._id}, {$set: {"attachments.0.selected": true}});
```

This helps in the case where you have a large number of attachments for a given document. This would be faster for the DB to execute, however, I'm unclear if the server will just publish the entire document back to the user anyway. i.e. this will probably help but may not be a big win.

### publish less data

On the server, you could try to selectively remove fields from `InspectionOrders` when you publish them. For example:

```
Meteor.publish('inspectionOrders', function() {
  return InspectionOrders.find({}, {
    fields: {'attachments.hugeBinaryFile': 0}
  });
});
```

This helps in the case where you are just publishing a lot of extra data with each document. Your documents will sync much faster if you put less data on the wire.

Comment: In the current DDP spec, updates send individual fields, but they wont granularly send partial fields in the case of arrays/objects. So I think the first solution might cause less data to be sent to the server, but the same amount to be sent back down to the client.

Comment: I updated the question with some more info. The problem isn't really the speed of Mongo find or update. It's the fact that a whole bunch of other connected data is populated using reference keys. And this data gets re-loaded every time the `InspectionOrder` object is updated.